# How to place two Linear Layout on each other?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, android-linearlayout

I try to develop a game using Kotlin where you shall guess a random word. I'd like a "keyboard" for the guessing where the raws of the keyboard would be Linear Layouts with full of Buttons. Something like this:

A B C D E *
F G H I J *
. . . . .,

where A,B,C,D,E are 5 Buttons contained by a Linear Layout. At the * sign the Linear Layout ends and from F-J there is an another Linear Layout. They shall be under each other and not next to each other.

I cannot place a linear layout to another one because they overlap. I tried RelativeLayout, tried LinearLayout with aligning the Top to the other Linear Layout's bottom, but nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution would be to use `LinearLayout` with `orientation` set to  `vertical`, which can contain multiple `orientation=horizontal` `LinearLayout`s (for each row of letters)

but there are better `View`s for such purpose, e.g. [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout), [`GridView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView), [`TableLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout)...

Comment: Thank you for the alternatives.

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer when helpful :) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TableLayout, something like this:

```
<TableLayout>
     <TableRow>
         <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- the views you need here -->
         </LinearLayout>

     </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

You have the table, and for every TableRow you put, you can use a vertical oriented LinearLayout to put the TextView, Buttons or whatever you need